# v-if not switching back after second change

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

I have this form that i need to switch to other component (currently the same with different label, don't have it prepared yet) depends on true/false from select input.

```
<div v-if="form.is_one === true" class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-5/6">
    <text-input v-model="form.name" :error="form.errors.name" label="Name 1" />
</div>
<div v-else class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-5/6">
    <text-input v-model="form.name" :error="form.errors.name" label="Name 2" />
</div>
<select-input v-model="form.is_one" :error="form.errors.is_one" class="pb-8 pr-6 w-full lg:w-1/6" label="switch">
    <option value="true">yes</option>
    <option value="false">no</option>
</select-input>
{{ form.is_cc }}
```

Value is passed (by default true) in:

```
return {
    form: this.$inertia.form({
        name: null,
        is_one: true,
    }),
}
```

[And while on page render it does render properly (true, label "Name 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuQw2.png)

[And on first switch it changes as well, (false, label "Name 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVXNV.png)

[On next change it does not changes back, as you can see below form the value changed to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxnMU.png)

Can't see what would be the error here, there is nothing in console.log about it. If there is a better solution to switching component i can try it.

Comment: @Shoejep tried, didn't have different effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<option value="true">
```

This option sets `form.is_one` value to **string value** `"true"`, but your v-if checks for boolean `true`.  You can [bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) boolean true/false to your `<option>` values and  then your v-if will work

```html
<option :value="true">yes</option>
<option :value="false">no</option>
```